# Как вернуть из метода template класса наследника этого класса?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Имеется класс:

```
template <class T>
class Enumerable
{

public:
    Enumerable(Enumerator<T>* enumerator)
            : m_enumerator(enumerator) {} ;

    Enumerator<T>* getEnumerator()
    {
        return m_enumerator;
    }

    template<class V>
    Enumerable<V>* select(const std::function<V (const T&)>& selector)
    {
        const auto selectHandler = [&selector](Enumerator<V>* parent)
        {
            if (nullptr == parent || !parent->hasNext())
                return T();

            parent->moveNext();
            return selector(parent->current());
        };

        return new LazyEnumerable<T, V>(new LazyEnumerator<T, V>(m_enumerator, selectHandler));
    }

protected:
    Enumerator<T>* m_enumerator;
};
```

Как видите метод *select(..)* возвращает наследника этого класса, однако на момент компиляции *Enumerable* класс *LazyEnumerable*, являющийся наследником - незаконченный тип, компилятор выдает ошибку:

error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class LazyEnumerable<int, int>' 
32 |         return new LazyEnumerable<T, V>(new LazyEnumerator<T, V>(m_enumerator, selectHandler));

*LazyEnumerable* выглядит следующим образом:

```
template <class T, class V>
class LazyEnumerable : public Enumerable<T>
{
public:
    LazyEnumerable(LazyEnumerator<T, V>* enumerator)
        : Enumerable<T>(enumerator) {}

    QueryableVector<T> toVector()
    {
        QueryableVector<T> vector;
        if (nullptr == this->m_enumerator)
            return vector;

        while (this->m_enumerator->hasNext())
        {
            this->m_enumerator->moveNext();
            vector.pushBack(this->m_enumerator->current());
        }
        return vector;
    }
};
```

Вопрос следующий: как реализовать использование и возврат наследника из метода базового класса, если базовый класс является *template'ом*?

Пробовал использовать *forward declaration*, но ошибка та же.

Comment: Наверняка вы изначально все усложняете. Думаю лучше пересмотреть архитектуру проекта и  роли классов

Answer (score 2):

Сначала спасёт изменение типа нового объекта с `new LazyEnumerable<T, V>` на `new LazyEnumerable<V, T>` . Тогда возвращаемый тип `Enumerable<V>* select` уже будет совместим  с родственным.

Или в зависимости от вашего алгоритма поменяйте только возвращаемый тип, а новый объект оставляйте `new LazyEnumerator<T, V>` :

```
template<class V>
Enumerable<T>* select(const std::function<V (const T&)>& selector);
```

И только после определения класса `LazyEnumerable` уже можно будет задать код метода `select`.

Примерно так :

```
template <class T>
class Enumerable{
public:
    template<class V>
    Enumerable<T>* select(const std::function<V (const T&)>& selector);
};

template <class T, class V>
class LazyEnumerable : public Enumerable<T>{
  ..
};

template    <class  T>
template    <class  V>
Enumerable<T> * Enumerable<T>::select(const std::function<V (const T&)>& selector){
    ..
    return new LazyEnumerable<T, V>(new LazyEnumerator<T, V>(m_enumerator, selectHandler));
}
```